# Multithreading trouble with notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing an exercise to simulate a waiting queue in a shop with multiple threads.

I have a waiting list and 2 counters
When a client is first of the waiting list and a counter is free, the client enters the counter wait for 2 secs, notify other clients then leave.

I don't undestand why waiting client are never notified. 
(I read many others topics but I couldn't find an answer).

```
package tp;
import java.util.Random;
public class Client extends Thread{

    private static Counters counters = new Counters(2);
    private static WaitingQueue queue = new WaitingQueue(3);
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static Integer client_counter = 1;
    private Integer id;

    public Client(){
        this.id = client_counter++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Client client = new Client();
                client.start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

   public void run() {   
       boolean end = false;
       System.out.printf("Client %d come in the shop\n", this.id);
       if (queue.enter(this)) { // false if queue is full
           System.out.printf("Client %d go in the waiting queue\n", this.id);
           while (!end) {
               try {
                   end = this.waitToEnter();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }

    private synchronized boolean waitToEnter() throws InterruptedException{
        while ( (!queue.isFirst(this))) { 
// return true if client is first in the queue
            System.out.printf("Client %d wait to be first\n", this.id);
            wait();

        }
        int nb = counters.entrer(this); 
// return -1 if no free counter else index of the counter
        while (nb == -1) {
            System.out.printf("Client %d for a free counter\n", this.id);
            wait();
            nb = counters.entrer(this);
        }
        this.enterCounter(nb);
        notifyAll();
        return true;
    }

    private void enterCounter(int nb) throws InterruptedException {
        queue.leave(this);
        System.out.printf("Client %d in counter %d\n", this.id, nb);
        this.sleep((long) 2000 + random.nextInt(1000));
        System.out.printf("Client %d out of counter %d\n", this.id, nb);
        counters.leave(this, nb);
    }
}



package tp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Counters {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> counters = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

   public Counters(int nb_guichets) {
       /* Set all counter to free*/
       for (int i = 0; i < nb_guichets; i++) {
            counters.add(i, true);
       }
   }

   public synchronized int entrer(Client client) {
       /* if a counter is free return its index else -1 */
       for (int i = 0; i < counters.size(); i++) {
           if (counters.get(i)) {
               counters.set(i,false);
               return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }

   public void leave(Client client, int nb) {
       counters.set(nb, true);
   }
}




package tp;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WaitingQueue {

    public ArrayList<Client> waiting_list = new ArrayList();
    private int waiting_list_size;

   public WaitingQueue(int size) {
      this.waiting_list_size = size;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {

       return waiting_list.size() == 0;
   }

   public boolean isFirst(Client client) {
      return waiting_list.get(0).equals(client);
   }

   public synchronized boolean enter(Client client) {
      boolean res = false;
      if(waiting_list.size() < waiting_list_size) {
          res = waiting_list.add(client);
      }
      return res;
   }

   public synchronized void leave(Client client) {
      waiting_list.remove(client);
   }
}
```

log :

```
Client 1 come in the shop
Client 1 go in the waiting queue
Client 1 in counter 0
Client 2 come in the shop
Client 2 go in the waiting queue
Client 2 in counter 1
Client 3 come in the shop
Client 3 go in the waiting queue
Client 3 for a free counter
Client 4 come in the shop
Client 4 go in the waiting queue
Client 4 wait to be first
Client 5 come in the shop
Client 5 go in the waiting queue
Client 5 wait to be first
Client 1 out of counter 0
Client 6 come in the shop
Client 2 out of counter 1
Client 7 come in the shop
Client 8 come in the shop
```

Comment: You need to re-post this question, because the source-code that you included doesn't generate the log-output that you included.  It doesn't seem to include any "notification" code.  Thus, your question as presently posted is un-answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sbgermanm for trying, I found that solution as well but I specific rules and Wait and Notify had to be in the Client code.

I was tricked by the Java syntax but in the end it was really easy:

To synchronized multiple thread first you need an object instance shared by all the Threads.

That was my case with the object WaitingQueue. Then call the Wait() function on that object. Wait() put the current Thread in a Waiting State not the object you used to call Wait().

Here's the trick.

```
// Put the current thread in Waiting State
Synchronized(sharedInstance) {
   sharedInstance.Wait()
}

// Wakes up all the thread sharing sharedInstance
Synchronized(sharedInstance) {
   sharedInstance.NotifyAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wait` and `notify`/`notifyall` work on the object they are called on. You are creating lots of different client objects, so each object has its own monitor.

You should probably stick to using classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package to do synchronization (e.g., `Semaphore`).

If you want to stick with the object synchronization methods (as an exercise) you need to modify your code to have a single object on which you wait and notify.

Comment: I got to stick to the basic libraries, it's an exercises :/

Answer (score 0):

there are some things to do with this code:

**You use the thread instance as monitor object** 
so each thread is "notifyall" only to himself. I.E, when "client 1" leaves the counter and do notifyAll(), it is doing client1.notifyall(). Client 3 has done client3.wait(). So you are notifying to the incorrect monitor object

I recomend you to use always explicit object before wait() or notify(). In this case is this.wait() and is incorrect.

I haven't done but it is very easy to see this, if you use jconsole you must have three thread on "waiting state", two of the on the first wait() and another on the second wait().

**You have two diferents conditions here** 
You are using one notify for to differents things: to notify you are leaving the queue and you are leaving the counter... It is better use conditions for that...

**You are using the monitors on the threads body instead of the resources body**
It is on the queue method and counters method where I will put this monitors.

**Try this (or better not, it it better DIY)**
If you want to use wait/notify as an exercice, try this way (I try to modify you code at less as I can and again I haven't try it and it is not the good way, it is much better with Conditions)

```
package tp;

import java.util.Random;

public class Client extends Thread {

    private static Counters counters = new Counters(2);
    private static WaitingQueue queue = new WaitingQueue(3);
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static Integer client_counter = 1;
    private Integer identity;
    public Integer getIdentity() {
        return identity;
    }

    public void setIdentity(Integer identity) {
        this.identity = identity;
    }

    private static Object monitor = new Object();

    public Client() {
        this.identity = client_counter++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Client client = new Client();
                client.start();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean end = false;
        System.out.printf("Client %d come in the shop\n", this.identity);
        if (queue.enter(this)) { // false if queue is full
            System.out.printf("Client %d go in the waiting queue\n", this.identity);
            while (!end) {
                try {
                    end = this.waitToEnter();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Client %d leave the shop\n", this.identity);
    }

    private  boolean waitToEnter() throws InterruptedException {
        queue.waitTillFirst(this);
        System.out.printf("Client %d is the first in queue\n", this.identity);
        int nb = counters.waitTillEnter(this);
        queue.leave(this);
        this.enterCounter(nb);
        return true;

    }

    private void enterCounter(int nb) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.printf("Client %d in counter %d\n", this.identity, nb);
        this.sleep((long) 2000 + random.nextInt(1000));
        System.out.printf("Client %d out of counter %d\n", this.identity, nb);
        counters.leave(this, nb);
    }
}

package tp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Counters {

    private ArrayList<Boolean> counters = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public Counters(int nb_guichets) {
        /* Set all counter to free */
        for (int i = 0; i < nb_guichets; i++) {
            counters.add(i, true);
        }
    }

    public synchronized int entrer(Client client) {
        /* if a counter is free return its index else -1 */
        for (int i = 0; i < counters.size(); i++) {
            if (counters.get(i)) {
                counters.set(i, false);
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public synchronized void  leave(Client client, int nb) {
        counters.set(nb, true);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int waitTillEnter(Client client) throws InterruptedException {
        int nb = entrer(client);
        // return -1 if no free counter else index of the counter
        while (nb == -1) {
            System.out.printf("Client %d waiting for a free counter\n", client.getIdentity());
            wait();
            nb = entrer(client);
        }
        return nb;
    }
}
package tp;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WaitingQueue {

    public ArrayList<Client> waiting_list = new ArrayList();
    private int waiting_list_size;

   public WaitingQueue(int size) {
      this.waiting_list_size = size;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {

       return waiting_list.size() == 0;
   }

   public boolean isFirst(Client client) {
      return waiting_list.get(0).equals(client);
   }

   public synchronized boolean enter(Client client) {
      boolean res = false;
      if(waiting_list.size() < waiting_list_size) {
          res = waiting_list.add(client);
      }
      return res;
   }

   public synchronized void leave(Client client) {
      waiting_list.remove(client);
      notifyAll();
   }

    public synchronized void waitTillFirst(Client client) throws InterruptedException {
        while ((!isFirst(client))) {
            // return true if client is first in the queue
            System.out.printf("Client %d wait to be first\n", client.getIdentity());
            wait();
        }

    }
}
```